# Why can't I call an SQL select based on the primary key?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, primary-key

I have a pretty simple table with 5 columns:

key, datetime, title, body, image

The user selects a title from a dropdown box and a form is populated with the datetime, body, and image. When I try to select by key nothing happens. However, If I select by title it works.

doesn't work:

```
SELECT body FROM myTable WHERE key='140'
```

works:

```
SELECT body FROM myTable WHERE title='hello world'
```

I've tried this by typing the query directly into phpMyAdmin and it gives me an error saying there is a problem at 'key='140''.

Comment: That would be "Why *can't* I" then...

Comment: I am amazed when people notice stuff like that. I honestly didn't event notice that typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html). You should surround it with backticks:

```
SELECT body FROM myTable WHERE `key`='140'
```

Comment: Hah, we both found the same link.

Comment: i just renamed my key to pkey and it works. thanks! not sure why that didn't dawn on me. It's always the most simple things you miss when your nose is buried in code.

Comment: "pkey" is only a marginal improvement over "key". As a name it tells you nothing about the data. A name should tell the user what the column is and each data element name ought to be unique within the database.

Answer (score 2):

Because most likely key is numeric

try:

```
SELECT body FROM myTable WHERE key=140
```

without the quotes

Comment: This is the answer I would have given.  mySql is less forgiving than MS SQL in the use (or lack thereof) of quotes around numeric fields.

Answer (score 1):

Or possibly a combination of the two answers already given.  A numeric key with a reserved word:

```
SELECT body FROM myTable WHERE `key`=140
```

Answer (score 0):

Because key is a reserve word on SQL.

you can use

SELECT body FROM myTable WHERE [key]='140'